# Smooth approximation of characteristic function of a bounded open set

Tags: general-topology, analysis, partial-differential-equations, approximation-theory

Let $U$ be an open bounded set of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is it possible to approximate $\chi_U$ as almost everywhere limit of increasing sequence of smooth functions?

Comment: @julien: [Mollifiers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollifier) and mollifying sequence. Approximation of the identity is fine, too.

Comment: @Martin Thanks, Martin. Mollifier...that's a nice word.

Comment: @julien: I should have mentioned "convolve/take the convolution with smooth bump functions", too.

Answer (score 3):

Let 
$$f_n(x)=\frac{n}{\sqrt{\pi}}e^{-(nx)^2}$$
which has integral $1$ and approaches the dirac delta function as $n\to \infty$. Then the convolution $\chi_U*f_n$ is smooth for each $n$ as $f_n$ is smooth and we have
$$\frac{d^k}{dx^k}\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_U(t)f_n(x-t)dt=\int_{\mathbb R}\chi_U(t)\frac{d^kf_n}{dx^k}(x-t)dt$$
and converges everywhere to $\chi_U$.

Comment: In the OP there is the requirement that the sequence $f_n$ be *increasing* (and on $\mathbb{R}^n$, instead of $\mathbb{R}$). This sequence won't be increasing.

Comment: @Martin Whoops, I missed that. I'll try and think of something, otherwise delete this answer.

Comment: I'd start with an exhaustion of $U$ by compact sets such that $K_{n} \subseteq \operatorname{int} K_{n+1}$. Take $\varepsilon_n$ so small that the $2\varepsilon_n$-neighborhood of $K_n$ is still contained in $\operatorname{int} K_{n+1}$. Then mollify the characteristic function of $K_{n}$ with a bump function whose support is contained in a ball of radius $\varepsilon_n$ around the origin to get $f_{n}$. Then the sequence $f_{2n}$ should be increasing. I leave the details to you (if you want).

Comment: http://www.opentradingsystem.com/quantNotes/Convolution_and_smoothing_.html